# Prevent website from requesting a given file

Tags: .htaccess

Using htaccess, is there any way to prevent my website from downloading a file from a particular URL?

A simple example: I don't control a file downloaded by a third party movie player. I want to stop that player, so that it doesn't make any request.

Is this possible?

I try to explain better:

- I have a website;
- the website features a third party movieplayer;
- the movieplayer doesn't only play movies;
- it requests a file too (without the user knowing);
- this file is blocked by common ad-blocking softwares;
- I want to block the file before it is requested, even if the user has no ad-blocking software;

I hope I explained better   :-)

Comment: Are you saying that currently, your website can be made to download a file by a third party movie player ?

Comment: Please rewrite your question. It is hard to understand what you are explaining.

Comment: The third party movieplayer downloads a file that I can't control: I want to prevent this player from downloading that file. The downloaded file is NOT a video, but code to track the user (it gets blocked by common ad blockers: I want to block it without adblocker before it can be served)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the movieplayer is actually executed on the web server, you might have some way to block the request. However, you would need to use something other than `.htaccess` to do that: `iptables` might be a possible solution in this case.

But typically the movieplayer is downloaded from your website to the client browser and then it will request the problem file from there. So it will be the client host that requests the file, not the webserver host. The `.htaccess` file can only restrict how the webserver responds to the client: it cannot determine what the client will do with the data the client will receive from your site. The concept of "data" here includes movieplayer programs the client browser might execute.

Your only chance to prevent the movieplayer from downloading the file at the client would be to somehow modify the movieplayer (or its inputs) to make it not do that, or at least retarget its request to 127.0.0.1 or some other location that would cause the request to quickly and reliably fail.

If you cannot modify the movieplayer, then you may have to remove it from your site and find another movieplayer with less annoying side effects. Perhaps you could use the video features of HTML5 instead of using any movieplayer at all?
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: After a lot of research I came to the same conclusions but I posted my question anyway. Thanks